# How do I add a full site search to a website in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a HTML5 website and I need to create a site search box that
displays results in a results page with description and photo.
How would I go about this.
I have looked alot and only see google search and thats not what im after.
Can this be done without PHP or RAILS?
Looking for purely JS and html5 and css and jquery.
Thanks and a point i the correct direction would be great.

Example is this Wordpress sites search http://agroamerica.com/
I dont want to use WP but hand code it.
Any help is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet, given that you don't want to implement a third party indexing service, would be to set an indexing function on your server's back end to handle search requests. You mentioned Rails, and [there are some pretty great gems for this](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_search).

One point of trouble you will have with this question is that, in my experience, full site search functionality without a back end / database to query is not a very useful solution for any applications I've seen.

However, given that you want to keep it JS, you might look into the MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express.js, Angular.js, Node.js) which does some pretty sweet things like two-way data binding. It's a pure Javascript solution (albeit not a purely-front end solution).

Honestly, it sounds like you might be taking too big of bites to start off with. Try working through a scripting language on a site like Code Academy and learning about basic web application setups like MVC (a common way to handle different parts of a web application (used by the aforementioned Rails)). Stack Overflow users can be pretty brutal when you ask questions about advanced functionality without some understanding of the functionality's underlying elements or functional requirements, and search engines from the ground up have historically been the thing of doctoral dissertations.

Good luck!

Comment: I may be biting off more than I can chew here.
I will learn Rails before I tackle this.